# Some format specifier in C

Tags: types, primitive-types

Please give me the format specifier for following data type in C.

unsigned char, signed char, unsigned int, signed int, unsigned short int, signed int, short int, long int, unsigned long int, signed long int, long long, long double

Comment: That are the format specifiers, no?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Very lazy, suggest you try Google next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the ones that I know for sure:

unsigned char: `%u` (make sure your output is declared as unsigned char)

ex:

```
unsigned char test = 500;
printf("%u", test);
```

unsigned int: `%u`

signed int: `%i` or `%d`

unsigned short int: `%hu` might work. If not: `%d` or `%u` should be fine as well.

signed int: `%d` or `%i`

short int: `%d`

long int: `%ld`

unsigned long int: `%lu`

signed long int: `%ld` (not sure about this one).

long long: `%lld` or `%llu` if unsigned

long double: `%Lf`

Answer (score 0):

***RTFM***

This is what you asked for:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx

This is more use:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx